# Is calling someone 'didactic' risking offense?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, offensive-language, epithet-requests

As I understand it, 'didactic' is used to mean something that has the ulterior motive of teaching especially in a moral connotation and also to mean patronising, or appearing patronising.

So does describing someone or someone's manners as didactic make it an offensive comment, or indeed simply mean they have the inclination to teach, moral or otherwise?

Greek being my mother tongue, I know the word stems from the greek 'διδακτικός' meaning 'someone who teaches' though in a non-professional manner, but I don't know if the word's meaning has been adapted through the language transition.

Comment: As a native English speaker, I can't see why it would be considered offensive.

Comment: Can you provide an example of "didactic" being used in a patronizing way? I've never heard it used in a negative context, most of the time it's neutral or slightly positive.

Comment: Patronizing way: "_Oh dear, you're always so **didactic** with our dinner guests – sweetheart, they're not here to learn, they're here for cocktails!_"    Or like "_Geez, stop being such a **didact** all the time, Scott, my gawd!_"

Comment: @OddCore, I would note that "**didactic**" does _not_, in isolation, connote anything ulterior or untoward regarding the motivations behind the didact's motive(s), but it certainly is pretty easy to choose phrasing that shades the  term toward a negative connotation.

Comment: @Blubberguy22 I'm not sure I'd say *patronizing* as such, as much as pushy and unwanted. Like if somebody describes a novel as "didactic", it suggests the author has spent a lot of time lecturing the reader through a character's mouth rather than telling their story.  It may not be a bad thing, necessarily, but if you're just here for a good scifi story, you may not be happy about a ten page screed on the evils of wearing pants jammed into the middle of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not clear from a dictionary definition, but it is usually employed in a  negative sense. Consider some of these recent examples from the OED:

> 1979   J. B. Ingram Curriculum Integration & Lifelong Educ. iv. 66
>   This one-sided view..portrays teaching as didactic, theoretical, and
>   ego-centric, the teacher being active, but the learner passive.
>
> 2009   S. Cross Adult Teaching & Learning i. 9   Techniques identified
>   as teacher-centred have come to mean all that is didactic, boring,
>   self-serving and neglectful.
>
> 2011   Daily Tel. 14 May 21   In drink the middle-aged male is a
>   repugnant beast—bossy, loud, didactic and know-all.

**I think the main problem is that it has come to imply a form of teaching in which the pupil plays little part but as recipient of information. And I suppose you could say that it is critical, if not mildly offensive to call someone's writing *didactic***

Comment: Bah, these uses are just another way of saying "**mansplaining**" or just clueless or drunk or whatever.   It certainly can be used as a sign of respect – it's just that not everyone wants "to be lectured [at]".

Comment: @davidmacCaryrichter Mansplaining is specifically explaining something *that the subject already knows* because the speaker has unfairly assumed their audience is ignorant. Didactic doesn't necessarily imply the audience already knows the subject, but it often means the lecture is out of place or excessively long.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a commonly used word, but if we look at definition 2, here (which you refer to with your comment about appearing patronising), we can see that it's quite insulting.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/didactic

```
adjective

1.intended for instruction; instructive: didactic poetry.
2.inclined to teach or lecture others too much: a boring, didactic speaker.
3.teaching or intending to teach a moral lesson.
4.didactics, (used with a singular verb) the art or science of teaching.
```

With all language comprehension, we have to consider the **motives** of the speaker, ie what were they really trying to communicate?  So, if I was a teacher, and one of my students told me that I was didactic, then I could, according to the definition, think  "That's fine, she's simply saying that I'm a teacher".  However, since we both **already know** that I'm a teacher, her motivation for saying it with this meaning doesn't make sense - she would just be stating the obvious, it's completely pointless.

So, I would then assume that she **didn't** mean definition 1, and that she probably meant definition 2: the motivation makes sense here, as she's telling me that I come off as patronising - she's either insulting me or she's trying to help me realise how to be a better teacher.  So, I might be insulted, or I might "take it on the chin" and try to not be as patronising in future.

Either way, she **risks offense** (which is really what your question should be asking: deciding that something is *objectively, inherently offensive* can be difficult, and is prone to debate.  It's more useful to ask if you **risk** offending people - that's a much easier question to answer.)

EDIT: this answer may appear didactic.  Apologies if so.

Answer (score 0):

Some words I choose to define a certain way, because it seems burning with emotion to consider another.  I guess this would be one of those words.  For me, the most valuable use of this word has a precondition, however.  That is, it should be reasonable to believe that the context of circumstances of the object of the word should be easily described as unusual for teaching or nearly impossible conditions for teaching without offending.  In this context, the word "didactic" is primarily then useful as a gesture of gratefulness when a speaker is choosing to risk negativity to teach, also assuming the speaker is qualified within the subject to teach in the first place.  Long way to say that the word works for me when someone is teaching in an unconventional forum, and I then would like to express gratitude..."Your style is so didactic, and I have learned so much from you, thankyou."  No way in this context to use the positive of "didactive" against someone or to imply disappointment with someone.  Again, not with the positive use of the word (non-negative use).

The realest use of this word is as a way to plainly describe the style of "teach speech"...simply as a matter of fact the way to describe the type of speech contained in the teaching method.

Answer (score 0):

As an educator, I use the term *didactic* to imply that something is *teaching-centered* rather than *learning-centered*. My point in doing so is to indicate that what someone is doing merely satisfies some abstract notion of what the instructor thinks people should "know" and that the instructor is not aware of (or concerned with) the actual cognitive processes necessary for the learning objective.

However, I use the word mainly because I can't find a better one to communicate this idea.